Smarty issue with "conference_sessions" in confirmation email of event registration
Drupal 9.5.1 CiviCRM 5.68
I am preparing an event. There is a Smarty error which appears in the participant's confirmation email. I am not capable of correcting it. Is there some way I can suppress this error message?
Warning: Undefined array key "conference_sessions" in /home/amfamproject/www/friends/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php(2018) : eval()'d code on line 85
<-- Comment out this section End of Comment out -->

Line 85 is commented out: 'code block'
84  /** 85  * The directory where config files are located.
86   *
87  * @var string
88  * /
89    var sconfig_dir = 'configs';
90

can you paste the full email template for event registration?

I'm using the default template provided by civiEvent. The message is:   Thanks for registering for Orestes Brownson and The Future of American Constitutionalism.
We look forward to seeing you on June 20 at 4:30pm at the Capitol Visitor Center Room HVC-201AB.
If you have any questions, please contact us at obsymposium@amfamproject.org

I got a similar error on contribution_invoice template and it was fixed by the upgrade to civicrm 5.72.1. Can you try upgrading in case it fixes for you too?
